# how to smooth jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to smooth the chaining of some jquery.animate functions.

Here is a jsfiddle where I describe the problem :
http://jsfiddle.net/xavier_seignard/KTxbb/4/

As you can see, there is a stop between each animation, even with the linear attribute.

Do you have any idea about how to smooth it? Or anything else that would do the trick?

Regards

Comment: On fx 15/Mac I cannot see any stop between animation... you could observe this setting a duration of 2/3000 milliseconds

Comment: does anyone else see rendering problems with that fiddle?  With Chrome 21.0.1180.89 on MacOS X I see streaks left behind.  I've seen similar in my own code but hadn't been able to isolate it to a reportable test cast.

Comment: @Alnitak that's from you Video card

Comment: @MihaiIorga on my app it only started happening around Chrome 18, but I wasn't able to isolate it.  It happens on other cards on other Macs too.

Comment: @Alnitak , I've the same issue (chome 21/MacOs X)

Comment: @Alnitak Same issue on the latest Chrome on Windows 7 as well.

Comment: Hi! I would avise you use a "real" animation library like GreenSock's TweenLite : http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/

Comment: @ArmelL. seems interesting, especially the Timeline notion. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the speed for a more "fine" animation, you see that stop because the speed it's too fast and different size to cover:

```
function initPage() {
    $.each(json, function() {
        $("#point").animate({
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        },
        1000, 'linear');
    });
}​
```

Comment: that is a bit better, but I finally ended up using the jquery.crSpline  plugin (http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html) which automatically smooths the animation along a list of points. 
Here is a simple demo : http://xseignard.github.com/test-crspline/
and the associated code : https://github.com/xseignard/test-crspline/blob/master/js/site.js

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason this looks more like what your after is there's a bug in the original fiddle: you can't specify the animation type (`linear`) in the second parameter in the way you have it in your fiddle. The above code actually correctly specifies the linear attribute thus making it appear more how you want. That said jquery.crSpline is much more what you were probably after in the first place however.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just try out the jQuery Easing plugin - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Include the file and instead of "liner" add some other easing.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the change in speed that you're describing?

That is because the animations have the same timings but the distance the square box is covering differs. You might need to alter the time for each animation dependant in the distance travelled.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the problem with jsfiddle.. 
I tested your jsfiddle link and it was not looking great as you mentioned in your question.

But then I created new page on my pc and copied everything from your fiddle and checked it. It looks alright.

Copy and paste this and save it as html and test it :

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    #point {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px
}
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initPage()">
    <div class="start" id="point"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = [
                {'x' : '300' , 'y' : '200'},
                {'x' : '250' , 'y' : '150'},
                {'x' : '209' , 'y' : '387'},
                {'x' : '217' , 'y' : '323'},
                {'x' : '261' , 'y' : '278'},
                {'x' : '329' , 'y' : '269'},
                {'x' : '406' , 'y' : '295'}
            ];


function initPage() {
    $.each(json, function() {
        $("#point").animate({
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        },
        "linear");
    });
}
</script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tested on Windows 7 / Chrome 21 - works alright. The issue that was present in the fiddle is now gone.