# Adding ease to a jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i found this animation, which i would like to use to give my navigation links a tiny, gentle random movement, but it just doesn't look very smooth. http://jsfiddle.net/2TUFF/

([Random Movement in a Fixed Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774659/random-movement-in-a-fixed-container/13774719#13774719))

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    $container = ($container || $(window))
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv() {
    var $target = $('.a');
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv();
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}​
```

I've tried playing around with container size and speed but that doesn't help a lot, I also tried adding easing to the jquery myself but I have no knowledge of that mastery and failed.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me, what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: I want it to be as smooth as being moved by a light breeze,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html for smooth "light breeze" animations.

Related answer: [how to smooth jquery animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458237/how-to-smooth-jquery-animations)

Here is a full example in fiddle using `jQuery.crSpline`:

http://jsfiddle.net/2TUFF/295/

Comment: i really like the way it moves but how can i limit the movement now?

Comment: You can limit the boundaries by setting maxX and maxY. Right now it is based on the page dimensions, see these lines:

    `var maxX = $(document).width() - 100; var maxY = $(document).height() - 100;`